# How can I parse json using Java (android)

Tags: java, android, json

I have a JSON string and I need to extract a string from it using Java (android)

The JSON string look like that :

```
{
    "Header": {
        "context": {
            "change": {
                "token": 3191
            },
            "_jsns": "urn:zimbra"
        }
    },
    "Body": {
        "AuthResponse": {
            "authToken": [
                {
                    "_content": "token"
                }
            ],
            "lifetime": 43199998,
            "_jsns": "urn:zimbraAdmin"
        }
    },
    "_jsns": "urn:zimbraSoap"
}
```

I want to get the value of `_content`, which is "token" is this case.

What i tried:
NB: `result` contains the json string

```
//result contains the json string
JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(result);
String aJsonString = jObject.getString("Body");
JSONObject jResult = new JSONObject(aJsonString);
String aaa = jResult.getString("authToken");
```

At this point I get the following error :

`W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for authToken`

Any help will be appreciated

EDIT : Java code updated

Comment: Your JSON is an object. In there is a `Body` object. In the `Body` object is an `AuthResponse` object. In the `AuthResponse` object is your `authToken` array. You need to drill down the entire tree (root -> `Body` -> `AuthResponse` -> `authToken`), and you appear to be skipping a step or two.

Comment: `"Body"` is an **object**, not a string. Use `getJSONObject("Body")`. From that, get another object, and then you can get the token array

Comment: @4castle : Sorry, I missed a line.

Comment: Why the question is downgraded ? I can improve it if you give me feedbacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to traverse the JSON tree step by step

```
JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(result); 
JSONObject jBody = jObject.getJSONObject("Body");
JSONObject jAuthResponse = jBody.getJSONObject("AuthResponse");
JSONArray jauthToken = jAuthResponse.getJSONArray("authToken");
JSONObject jFirst = jauthToken.getJSONObject(0);
String aJsonString = jObject.getString("_content");
```

Comment: This is a bit bulky for extracting a single value. It could also be done as a one-liner with each step on a different line for readability.

Comment: @Merlevede : your code works fine replacing the last line with : `             String aJsonString = jFirst.getString("_content");`

Comment: @4castle : Can you give an exemple of a one liner or documentation about it ?

Comment: `String token = new JSONObject(result).getJSONObject("Body").getJSONObject("AuthResponse").getJSONArray("authToken").getJSONObject(0).getString("_content");`

Comment: @4castle It works fine, and it's more "classy". If you give an answer i'll accept it.

Comment: Questions can't get new answers once they are closed as a duplicate. No worries though, this answer is basically the same.

Comment: @Nab, if you know java, you could have guessed that you can chain all those lines in one single line. I did it on purpose for clarity!

Comment: @Merlevede Actually, I'm new to java. Dont take it bad, your answer is great.